# Network drives mapping from XP to 7

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, windows-xp

I am migrating multiple users from XP to 7 and they all have different mapped drives/locations on their current PC. After copying their all data from old PC to new PC, I am currently manually mapping their drives which consumes lot of time. Is there anyway of automating this process?

Is there any way of running a script on existing XP machine and running the same script on new Win 7 machine to map all the drives?

I am looking for a script or any other way of automating this process.

Thanks.

Comment: you could do it through group policy. otherwise you could use a command like `net use Z: \\server\share`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this for all your users, it would at least tell you what they had.

you'd probably want one central folder, lets say Mappings, so try

net use > \servername\Mappings\%username%_map.txt

Or try something like this
http://www.visualbasicscript.com/List-mapped-drives-on-remote-machine-m28529.aspx

Comment: Run that line from a GPO as a User Log on script (or the logon script assigned in AD user's property). Then you can parse the resulting text files and map things accordingly. I'm sure there are better ways to do this but this feels the most straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

out of boredom i quickly wrote a powershell script to help you out.

Run this on your workstation:
(newpcs and oldpcs must be in correct order so oldpc1 is the old pc of the user of newpc1)

```
$oldpcs=@("oldpc1", "oldpc2", "oldpc3")
$newpcs = @("newpc1", "newpc2", "newpc3")
$mapping = @{}

for($i=0;$i -lt $oldpcs.Count; $i++){

$mapping.add($oldpcs[$i], $newpcs[$i])

}

foreach ($comp in $oldpcs){

$m = Get-WmiObject win32_systemnetworkconnections -ComputerName $comp

$m | %{ 

#i know this is not very elegant but whatever
$temp = $_.partcomponent -split "="
$temp = $temp -replace "`"", ""
$temp2= $temp[1] -split " "
$driveletter = $temp2[1] -replace "\(", ""
$driveletter = $driveletter -replace "\)", ""
$path = $temp2[0] -replace "\\\\", "\"
$f = "C:\path\to\folder\" + $mapping.$comp + ".txt"

Add-Content $f "$driveletter;$path"
 }

}
```

Then get the file with corresponding computername to the new computer and run the following:

```
$txt = Get-Content "C:\path\to\file\$env:computername.txt"
$txt | % {
$temp = $_ -split ";"
net use $temp[0] $temp[1]
}
```

Remember that you have to run the mapping-script in the context of the user you want to map the drives for

Regards

P.S. Remotely mapping network drives is not possible afaik (i would love to be proven wrong)

You could create a logon script and map it to a user though